# Blank Window when I open RStudio (version 0.98) with R (version 3.2)

Tags: r, linux, debian, rstudio

I am using Debian (version 7.9) and I installed a not up-to-date version of R, together with RStudio 0.98.1103. Everything used to work!

As now I need the new version of R I uninstalled the previous one (2.15) and installed a new one (3.2.2) but now, when I try to open RStudio, I get a blank page!

Any suggestion how to solve the problem?

P.S. I could try to install the most recent RStudio version but here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206518/cant-open-rstudio-in-linux-debian-wheezy-error-glibc-2-14-not-found) they say it does not work with Debian version I have.

Comment: AFAIK you might need a newer RStudio version, but not necessarily the newest.

Comment: Uninstall your RStudio and install a newer version may be helpful.

Comment: Ok! Where can I find newer version for RStudio (but not the newest one)?